# Where do I begin to solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I've a problem:

$ye^{xy}+4y^3+(xe^{xy}+12xy^2-2y)y'=0 $

I can't begin to solve it because I don't know where to start.

Help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: Read up, or recall, something about exact differential equations... $Pdx+Qdy=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (e^{xy}) = ye^{xy}+xy'e^{xy}, $$
so that simplifies two terms. Next,
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(4xy^3) = 4y^3+12xy^2 y'. $$
Lastly,
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = 2yy', $$
and so the whole thing can be written as
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) = 0, $$
which is easy to solve. Solving the result of this for $y$, on the other hand, is not possible using elementary functions.